# Rotating an object while moving

Tags: game-maker

I have an object the is a perfect circle.  The object is moving left, right and jumping with collision detection.  What I am trying to do now is rotate the object while it is moving, so it looks like rolling.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
key_left = keyboard_check(vk_left);
key_right = keyboard_check(vk_right);
key_jump = keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space);

//1  right, -1 left
var move = key_right - key_left;
hsp = move * walkspd;
vsp = vsp + grv;


if(place_meeting(x, y + 1, oWall)) && (key_jump)
{
    vsp = -7;
}



//horizontal collisions 
if (place_meeting(x + hsp, y, oWall))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x + sign(hsp), y, oWall))
    {
        x = x + sign(hsp);
    }
    hsp = 0;
}
x = x + hsp;



//vertical collisions 
if (place_meeting(x , y + vsp, oWall))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x, y+ sign(vsp), oWall))
    {
        y = y + sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp = 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you not know how to draw a rotated sprite or are you having trouble determining how far to rotate it? Note: A full rotation is equal to a circumference (roll distance) of pi*D where D is the diameter of your circle

Comment: I have only tried to to use the inbuilt function image_angle = 1;

Answer (score 1):

For an exact roll of the circle object based on his displacement use this exact line at the end of your code:

```
image_angle -= hsp*pi;
```

The reason of a minus sign is because the roll is clockwise when you go to the right but angles in Game Maker are increasing counter clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is this in the Step Event:

```
image_angle += hsp;
```

`image_angle` is a variable that decides the rotation position of the sprite. In a number between 0 and 360. You can let it move by adding value to it.

And in case you didn't knew, `x += hsp` does the same thing as `x = x + hsp`. But the former makes them more readable.